# R code error shows that 'Must be a matrix'

Tags: r, matrix

#I am struggling running plspm in r.

```
>data1 <-data[data$SN1 == 1,]

>data2 <-data[data$SN2 == 2,]

>dataD <-data[data$SND == 3,]

>View(data1)
```

#Inner Model

```
>path_matrix <- matrix(c(0, 1, 1,
                    0, 0, 1,
                    0, 0, 0), nrow = 3, ncol = 3, byrow = TRUE)

>rownames(path_matrix) <- colnames(path_matrix) <- c("SS", "FOMO", "BI")

>is.matrix(path_matrix)

>print(path_matrix)
```

## Outer Model

```
>blocks <- list(10:17,2:6,7:9) # replace with the actual column indices of your indicators

>str(path_matrix)


>plspm1 <- plspm(data1, blocks, path_matrix)

>plspm2 <- plspm(data2, blocks, path_matrix)

>plspmD <- plspm(dataD, blocks, path_matrix)
```

Error: 'path_matrix' must be a matrix.

I have checked the followings

```
>is.matrix(path_matrix)

>print(path_matrix)
```

I could see path_matrix is matrix, but still the error is that 'path_matrix' must be a matrix.

Comment: Not reproducible, provide a minimal working example and corresponding data using `dput()`.

Comment: are you sure the function arguments are in the correct order ... you could try naming them to be sure ... as the examle at https://github.com/gastonstat/plspm seems to have `plspm(data, paths, blocks ... )` which is different from your example